# Tensorbook (Razer x Lambda) Battery Management

Tags: laptop, battery, power-management, razer-synapse

My new Tensorbook is fully loaded, dual booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04. I want to optimize its battery life, but have not found anything that works yet.

Model no: RZ09-421

Product no: RZ09-0421PEL9

### Linux attempts

After following the [Ubuntu installation instructions](https://linrunner.de/tlp/installation/ubuntu.html) it said charge thresholds not supported. [Uninstalling power-profiles-daemon](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/installation.html#conflict-with-power-profiles-daemon) and [enabling service units](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/installation.html#must-i-enable-tlp-s-systemd-service-units) didn't change the output.

### Windows 10 attempts

Windows settings didn't appear to include any power management settings, and neither does [Razer Synapse](https://www.razer.com/synapse-3) which came pre-installed. My Lenovo Legion's equivalent, [Vantage](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/videos/nvid500286), does have settings like what I'm looking for (they persist in Linux on that machine too).

If a solution doesn't already exist, how would I go about creating one myself?

Answer (score 0):

> My Lenovo Legion's equivalent, Vantage, does have settings like what
> I'm looking for (they persist in Linux on that machine too).

This is your answer. Battery Threshold Management is a BIOS (UEFI) issue and not an operating system issue.

My Lenovo Laptops have Lenovo Vantage, and I set Battery Threshold in Vantage (using my Windows System) to 80%.  This is the generally accepted charge rate for leaving laptops permanently connected to an AC Adapter.

Beyond that, Windows does have Power Management settings and so also does my Ubuntu Machine but this does not include threshold management.

> If a solution doesn't already exist, how would I go about creating one
> myself?

If the computer BIOS does not support Battery Threshold Management, you cannot create it. The computer must come with Battery Threshold Management.

In my case, Lenovo Laptops back to 2013 do have Battery Threshold Management.

The best advice for laptops without this capability is to charge it (not fully) and disconnect the AC Adapter.

Check with the Manufacturer to be sure what capabilities your laptop has.